# IE11 - SVG printing not showing all drawn elements

Tags: svg, printing, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to print my svg on IE, but only half of the svg is printed, the other half is hidden no matter how much `width` I set for the svg in `@media print`. Hope someone can help!

Here is the code:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="tree-area" ref="pageContent">
    <!-- SVG generated here -->
</div>



<!-- CSS -->
svg {
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 85vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000;
}

@media print {
  .tree-area {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  svg {
    border: 1px solid black;
    zoom: 0.75;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Current result:
[image]

Expected result:
[image]

Comment: It seems that IE cannot contain the entire page content in the print preview, maybe you can refer to [this similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437162/scaled-element-gets-cut-off-when-printing-in-ie11), it may be helpful to you. Or you can refer to [this document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-or-reset-internet-explorer-settings-2d4bac50-5762-91c5-a057-a922533f77d5#ie=ie-11) to reset IE settings. If it doesn't work for you, please provide a page code example that reproduces the problem, thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @XudongPeng Tks for your comment, btw do you have any documents about print page's structure? My printed content lies pretty deep in the center of the print page, left a lot of blank spaces even I've set page `margin: 0mm`

Comment: Have you tried adding the `!important` attribute to the element styles in `@media print`? Here is [a similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942969/css-media-print-not-working-at-all).